# Unable to load reference library - The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Tags: .net, compilation, reference

I have a class library which I maintain in it's own project/solution. It contains a few basic functions I've written, that I use in some older VB.NET applications mainly.

I'm doing some work on one such application, and it has required changes to the Library assembly as well as the main application. However, I'm finding that when I change and compile the library, when I come to re-compile the main application I get an error:

```
Error 8 Unable to load referenced library 'myLibrary.dll': The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
```

I've specified the 'myLibrary\bin\Release\myLibrary.dll' as the reference in the main project. I know in the past that I had the library project in the same solution, thus I could specify the project as a reference, rather than the release DLL, but I'd prefer to keep the projects separate.

Re-specifying the reference or reloading the main project solves the problem (temporarily at least), but I'd rather find a more sophisticated solution.

Comment: I did want to keep it as a standalone library - I can't remember now, but I had some problem with referencing the project. I guess I'll try copying the output via a post-build event, just for completeness. Can you elaborate on why you think referencing the project is preferred?

Comment: @David - I haven't been back to this problem in a while, but IIRC your suggestion (same VS Solution) was the only thing that offered respite. If you care to post it as an answer, you'll get the plaudits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why prefer to keep them separate? If they're part of the same codebase, they should be in the same solution. By short-circuiting this you're effectively limiting the development capabilities of Visual Studio with regards to the referenced assembly in the codebase. Additionally, referencing the `bin` output is very messy. If you want it to be a standalone library, have it build its output and copy that output to a `lib` folder somewhere. Then you can reference the final output, not the highly-transient `bin` directory.

Essentially, in terms of "find[ing] a more sophisticated solution," it's a matter of using the tooling that Visual Studio provides.  Organizing code into solution files is part of that tooling.

Answer (score 2):

When Visual Studio is refreshing it's Intellisense database, it will lock the file (.dll or .exe) that it is currently processing. It refreshes the Intellisense database every time you rebuild the solution, if I remember correctly (don't quote me on this though). Try waiting until VS is done with its Intellisense stuff before you try recompiling or running.

Comment: Thanks Daniel but this problem remains until I either recreate the reference or reload the project... I've left it for 30+ minutes between attempts.

Comment: You could also install [Unlocker](http://www.filehippo.com/download_unlocker/) and see which process locks the file. At least that'll give you an idea where to look next. Also, if you have multiple Visual Studios open, they may conflict with each other on the file.

Comment: "Multiple versions of Studio open" was my issue.  Thanks.